# How can I know how many files are stored in a tape?

Tags: freebsd, backup, tar, tape

I have installed an SCSI DDS4 tape drive and I have read:

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/el_GR.ISO8859-7/books/handbook/backups-tapebackups.html

and

https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/2.1.5-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/handbook/handbook127.html

I have managed to store with tar three directories to tape and retrieve them later.

What shall be done to read how many files are stored in a tape?

Edited>

```
% mt -f /dev/nsa0 eom
% mt -f /dev/nsa0 status
Drive: sa0: <SEAGATE DAT    9SP40-000 912L> Serial Number: HN0948V
---------------------------------
Mode      Density              Blocksize      bpi      Compression
Current:  0x24:DDS-2           variable       61000    enabled (DCLZ)
---------------------------------
Current Driver State: at rest.
---------------------------------
Partition:   0      Calc File Number:   4     Calc Record Number: -1
Residual:    0  Reported File Number:   4 Reported Record Number: 1266
Flags: None
%
```

I think it works

Comment: By file I mean "tar file". Like tar cvf /dev/sa0 mydir1  tark cvf /dev/sa0 mydir2 generates two "tar files", no matter how many files/directories are under mydir1 and mydir2

Comment: OK. I no longer have access to tape drives, but try this: `mt -f /dev/nsa0 eom` to get to the end of the data currently on the tape, followed by `mt -f /dev/nsa0 status` to output, among other things, the tape's current position, which will be the number of files that are on the tape.

Comment: It seems your suggestion works fine, I am almost sure I executed 4 times the tar file on that particular tape